# Android Studio use git for non-app directories

Tags: git, android-studio

I successfully implemented git in Android Studio.

The problem is, that I can not add the files to git as the project explorer does not show all directories, e.g. I would like to commit the .idea folder. I also have a folder called extras, which I want to put under git control. This was so much more easy with eclicpse where new files were also pointed out.

So basically I would like to git add all, without the files in .gitignore. Is there an easy way or do I have to use git bash?

Comment: Trust me, you do ***not*** want to commit any of the Idea folders/files to your project.  They all relate to you and your box.  If you're working with others it will add senseless conflicts and introduce unusual or inconsistent behavior between developers' boxes.

Comment: I maybe misusing git as a backup tool which is reproduced on my NAS and only I use it. Therefore I find the project settings an essential part of the backup.

Comment: Ultimately...yes, you are abusing Git here.  But you're also underestimating Android Studio.  Since you've got your dependencies managed by Gradle anyway, rely on that to tell you where to find the necessary JARs you need for the project.  Android Studio will *happily* reconstruct those files for you should they get lost.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! There is another tab called Commander where the whole directory tree is shown. Right click on any, Git - Add and you are set!